# I don't know what is wrong but my Django app isn't working I was studying a new course so any help please

Tags: python, django

> this my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

> this my sub-app URLs

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
   path ('', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

> This my Django-main App urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('food/',include('food.urls')),
]
```

> and browser is displaying this error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/food
Using the URLconf defined in firstapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, food, didn’t match any of these.
```

I am using Django -- 3.2.4 but the course that I am studying is using the 2.2.2 version

Answer (score 1):

Its best to stick with the version your working with or you will have alot of tranlsating to do. Which could actually be counter productive as your trying to learn  since many concepts/functions are deprecated and you really don't even need to worry about. (Unless of course you run into the code in the wild, at which point you'll understand whats it supposed to do)

Assuming your "*main app"*(project folder) is say "firstapp". And one of your installed apps is *"food"*. Make sure you have added the `food` app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
     'food',

]
```

Comment: Updated answer.